# "<private>" logs with AutoLayout issues in xcode

Tags: xcode, logging, autolayout

I recently had some issues related to AutoLayout, but can't figure what constraints are wrong - the logs look like:

```
[Layout] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
<private>

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<private>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, set a symbolic breakpoint on LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE to catch this in the debugger.
```

I did try setting the breakpoint at LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE and try to see if I can, but failed there too:

```
(lldb) p $arg1
(unsigned long) $0 = 4330017792
```

How can I log these constraints normally as we see every other constraints?

Checking some questions/forums I came to know that Apple introduced "Unified logging system", making some logs private, not imposing personal data to anyone. (I wonder what kind of personal data would have been revealed in logging constraints?)

I did have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344674/1208191) but didn't work for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be able to update your macOS? This should be fixed in 10.12.2. If you do still see  while debugging, please log a bug.

Your lldb command to print $arg1 should probably print as an object: po $arg1. Make sure you are on the stack frame named "LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE" (Xcode may automatically select the last frame that has symbols, so you may need to unfilter the debug navigator click to select that frame). The first argument to this function should be the view that has unsatisfiable constraints. Hopefully that will give you enough clues to proceed.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated to 10.12.4 and it logs the constraints issue normally (as before.)